# Row with button submitting wrong data to server

Tags: php, html, forms, session, mysqli

Ive been working on this issue for some time now, basically, i have a table and at the end of row is a button that submits that rows batchID and Priority value to my .php that handles post requests. the problem comes when i hit submit it takes the batchID column from the last row regardless of which button is pressed. i have this exact same code running on another site which works as intended. when i inspect the network data being sent it shows that all the data in column batchID is being sent to upload.php, but i only need the corresponding batchID to be sent.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "production_management");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
 exit();
}
require('databaseDetails.php');
session_start();
$userNameTmp = $_SESSION["usrName"];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Received Request Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="dashboard.php"><button class="button button2">Dashboard</button></a><p>
<form name="form" method="post" action="upload.php">
<div class="form">
<h1>Batch's</h1>
<p>Hello <?php echo $userNameTmp;?> </p>
<table class="responsive-table" width="100%" border="1" style="border- 
collapse:collapse;">

<thead>
<tr>
<th><strong>Started By</strong></th>
<th><strong>Batch Type</strong></th>
<th><strong>Date</strong></th>
<th><strong>Batch ID</strong></th>
<th><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
<th><strong>Progress</strong></th>
<th><strong>Priority</strong></th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM batch";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?> 
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["startedBy"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["batchType"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["date"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["batchID"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["quantity"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["progress"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["priority"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="postMethod" value="3"></td>
<td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="batchID" value="<?php echo 
   $row["batchID"]; ?>"></td>
<td align="center"><input type="submit" value="test"></td></tr>
<?php 
}
?>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are outputting the form in a loop and the `name` attributes on the fields all have the same name value

Comment: If you just want to submit one batch at a time, you need a separate `<form>` tag for each row, not one giant form.

Comment: Put the form around the field, so you have multiple forms, then the correct BatchID will get sent